# Xamarin can not read the file

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to read a Json file for my mobile app in Xamarin Studio, but it throws me an error

> can not find the file

While I try the same in Console Application every thing is all right.
I'm trying reading the file this way:

```
string Jason = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Folder\file.txt")
```

Comment: Have you tried bringing that file to the proper directory in your solution and trying that instead?

Comment: a mobile app has it's own sandboxed filesystem.  It can't read a file from your PC's C: drive - how would that work when your app is deployed on someone's phone?

Comment: "Mobile app", does whatever system you're creating this for even have a C: drive?

Answer (score 0):

This information is taken from Xam160 Class from Xamarin University. Within mobile application the platform generates a isolated folder area specifically for your App.  These are the preferred locations to store files specific to your App with AppHome representing the Root of your sandboxed area.

Android  - AppHome/files

iOS - AppHome/Lirbrary/[subdirectory]

Windows Phone - AppHome\Local

To Access these paths you can work with the Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration to access these locations with the Environment.GetFolder() Method.

```
//Android
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

//iOS
string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string libFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(docFolder,"..","Library");

// Windows has different implementation. GetFolder Path with throw exception on windows.
string path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
```

Each of these will get you access to the path you need to be able to read and write files locally on which platform you are on.